# Django 2.1 PasswordResetView 404

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to integrate the User password reset functionality into my custom user model. When I try to access the URL I get a 404-error.

The URL I try to access:
http://localhost:8000/reset/MQ/4zw-f78ac4c97d45f366a243/

My urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.LogOutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('password-change/', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(),
         name='password-change'),
    path('password-reset/', views.PasswordResetView.as_view(),
         name='password-reset'),
    path('password-reset-done/', views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
         name='password-reset-done'),
    path('reset/<uuid:uidb64>/<slug:token>/',
         views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
]
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from braces import views as bracesviews
from django.views import generic
from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm, PasswordResetForm, SetPasswordForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ugettext_lazy as _
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib import auth
# Create your views here.

User = get_user_model()


(...)


class PasswordChangeView(auth_views.PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    template_name = 'accounts/password-change.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    form_valid_message = _("Your password was changed!")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PasswordResetView(auth_views.PasswordResetView):
    form_class = PasswordResetForm
    template_name = 'accounts/password-reset.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:password-reset-done')
    subject_template_name = 'accounts/emails/password-reset-subject.txt'
    email_template_name = 'accounts/emails/password-reset-email.html'


class PasswordResetDoneView(auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView):
    template_name = 'accounts/password-reset-done.html'


class PasswordResetConfirmView(auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView):
    template_name = 'accounts/password-reset-confirm.html'
    form_class = SetPasswordForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    form_valid_message = _("Your password was changed!")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The function of sending the reset link is working. I get the email inside my console and the link I shown before is printing.

In my template file i already had to make an ugly hack....

```
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
    {% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at
        {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}

    {% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
    {% block reset_link %}
        {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/reset/{{ uid }}/{{ token }}/
    {% endblock %}
    {% trans "Your login email, in case you've forgotten, is same this email address:" %} {{ user.get_username }}

    {% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}

    {% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

I had to hardcore the URL since

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'accounts:password-reset-confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

simply wouldn't work and also gave me an error. Maybe someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong. Trying to figure this out for some time now.

Comment: your reset path requires a uuid and then a slug, you are passing MQ for uuid. MQ doesn't looks like a uuid to me 

Comment: I did not generate the uuid as MQ, but the solution of Alasdair worked great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

```
path('reset/<uuid:uidb64>/<slug:token>/',
     views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
     name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

However `uidb64` is not a uuid, it is a string like `MQ`.

To fix the problem, change the URL pattern to match the entry in [`django.contrib.auth.urls`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py):

```
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
```